# Scss Issue - Error is preventing me from seeing website

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm getting the following error in console when I'm saving my index.html file:

**error sass/_settings.scss (Line 9: invalid CSS after "...r-set defaults.: expected ":", was "$base-font-size..." on line 9 of sass/_settings.scss from line 2 of sass/app.scss**

I also get this error when refreshing my index.html page, and all styles are broken. I am using Foundation with Compass.

The following is in my _settings.scss file from lines 1 - 9:

```
//
// Foundation Variables
//

$top

// The default font-size is set to 100% of the browser style sheet (usually 16px)
// for compatibility with browser-based text zoom or user-set defaults.
$base-font-size: 100% !default;

// $base-line-height is 24px while $base-font-size is 16px
// $base-line-height: 150%;

// This is the default html and body font-size for the base em value.
```

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: Are `//` legal comments in scss? (I have never used it myself) They aren't comment in css and according to what you are saying - scss compiler seems to doesn't treat them as comment. Or perhaps you are trying to use not compiled scss as css file?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your $top variable. There is no ending `;` to the rule. So, this is an invalid syntax issue.

```
$top: 1;
```

... will fix your issue. Of course, you'll need to remove the variable, or assign a proper value as you see fit.